# Phrase search and highlighting with search:search in Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to search for a phrase with search:search and highlight that phrase (not individual words). For example if I am searching for search:search("lease coral") then following output is coming:-

```
<search:match path="fn:doc("abc.xml")/*:text>testing <search:highlight>Lease</search:highlight><search:highlight>CORAL</search:highlight></search:match>
```

It is highlighting lease and coral separately. But I want it to highlight "Lease Coral" together like a single phrase. Is there any way to get this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_44520

> "any phrase"  Anything within the double-quote marks is treated as a phrase. The example matches documents having the phrase "any phrase" (without the double-quote marks).

You can experiment with this using `search:parse`:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:parse('high time')
=>
<cts:and-query strength="20" qtextjoin="" qtextgroup="( )" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:word-query qtextref="cts:text">
    <cts:text>high</cts:text>
  </cts:word-query>
  <cts:word-query qtextref="cts:text">
    <cts:text>time</cts:text>
  </cts:word-query>
</cts:and-query>
```

That's an AND of two word-query terms. Now try this:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:parse('"high time"')
=>
<cts:word-query qtextpre="&quot;" qtextref="cts:text" qtextpost="&quot;" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:text>high time</cts:text>
</cts:word-query>
```

That's a simple word-query term - but the text is a phrase, which is what you want. Note the nested quotes.